# How to remove white space between text and table?

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

I am trying to place a table immediately below some text but `Latex` keeps putting it either above or at the bottom if the page.

I have using `FloatBarrier` but it has no effect. Removing the `t` option from the table places it at the bottom of the page creating a large gap of white space under the text. I also tried `\raggedbottom` which did not help.

I have read that [LaTeX inserts floats before text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) and I don't understand why it does so and how to put the table in the right order.

How can I place the table directly below the text?

This is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[style=numeric,autocite=plain,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{placeins}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\appendix  %
hello!
\FloatBarrier
\input{table}
\end{document}
```

And the table:

```latex
\begin{table*}[htbp]

    \caption{Title}
    \label{tab:table1}
    %\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l l l X @{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Authors} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Methods} & \textbf{Comments} \\
        \midrule
        \citeauthor{Name2020} & \citeyear{Name2020} & Method 1 & Comment 1 \\
        \midrule
        \citeauthor{Name2019} & \citeyear{Name2019} & Method 2 & Comment 2 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: the _only_ reason to wrap the `tabularx` in a `table` environment is to specify that it can be moved, so basically what you describe is expected. You are using `table*` which are spanning tables which can not come mid page after your text, perhaps you intended `table` for a single column table, and include `h` in the options.

Comment: `\FloatBarrier` will do nothing at the point that you have it as there are no pending floats at that point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My table  is large enough that is spans the two columns. I tried using `table` but it did not work very well as the table got squeezed into one column.

Comment: well if it spans two columns it can not possibly come  immediately after the one-column text `hello`. spanning floats go at the top or (with the stfloats package you are using, also the bottom) of the page.  It isn't clear what `[h]` would mean for a spanning float but it is not supported in any case.

Comment: This is why typesetting systems allow tables to float, allow it to float to the top of the page, give it a caption and refer to it indirectly by `the data in table~\ref{tab:table1}....`  rather than `the table below`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So how would you create an appendix section with a two column table other then putting the `Appendix` on the previous page?

Comment: you could use `\onecolumn` before the appendix then use an `[h]` table under the heading, or several other approaches, it all depends...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. Using `\onecolumn` gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-column floats can not come mid-page, but to get one under a heading you can usually do

```
\onecolumn
\section{Appendix whatever}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{zzzz}
\begin{tabular}...
```

To get a `[h]` here float under the heading in a single-column appendix of an otherwise two column document.